# Understanding proof in Walter Rudin's Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Doubt is that If $\gamma < \alpha$ then how does it follow that $\gamma$ doesnot belong to B and how does it follows that $\alpha \leq x $ for every $x$ in B

Also in next line how does this follows that if $\alpha < \beta $ then $\beta$ doesnot belongs to L

Thanks

Comment: L is the set of all lower bound of B and $\alpha$ is the supreme of L.if an element $\gamma$ <$\alpha$ ,it mean that $\gamma$ is belong to L and not belong to B

Comment: This theorem should probably specify that $L$ is the set of lower bounds of $B$ in $S$

Comment: If something is smaller than a lower bound of a set, then it can't be a member of the set.  g <a means g is not upper bound of L so there is a g <l <=a, where l in L.  So l is a lower bound of B. So g  is lower than a lower bound.  So l is not in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L is the set of lower bounds of B.

Let $l\in L;b\in B $.  As $l $ is a lower bound of $B $, $l\le b $ and therefore every element of $B $ is an upper bound of $L $.

So if $\gamma < \sup L $, $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of $L $ and thus not an element of $B $.

As for the second part.  $\alpha = \sup L $ so $\alpha $ is upper bound of $L $.  So $\alpha \ge l; \forall l\in L$.  So if $\beta > \alpha \ge l; \forall l\in L $, then $\beta $ can't be in $L $ because it is larger than every member of $L $.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma < \alpha$, then since $\alpha$ is the **least** upper bound of $L$, this means that $\gamma$ is **not** an upper bound of $L$, which means there is some $c \in L$ with $\gamma < c$. But $c \in L$, so $c$ is a lower bound of $B$, meaning every element of $B$ is at least as large as $c$, hence **strictly** larger than $\gamma$. So $\gamma$ is not in $B$.

Summarizing: if $\gamma < \alpha$, then $\gamma \not\in B$. Equivalently (take the contrapositive), if $\gamma \in B$, then $\gamma \geq \alpha$.

To answer your last question, $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $L$, so nothing larger than $\alpha$ can be in $L$. Therefore, if $\beta > \alpha$, then $\beta \not\in L$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of supremum, if $\gamma < \alpha$, then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of $L$. Since every element of $B$ is an upper bound of $L$, so $\gamma$ must not be in $B$.

Since $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $L$, if $\beta \in L$, then we have a contradiction that $\beta \leq \alpha $. So $\beta$ is not in $L$

Comment: You need to reconsider your answer in first line,$\gamma$ is in L.but you say it is not in L

Comment: @SathasivamK Thanks for the reminder, I typed it wrong.

Comment: Its my pleasure.@Bubububu

Answer (score 0):

L is the set of all lower bound of B and $\alpha$ is the supreme of L.if an element $\gamma$ <$\alpha$ ,it mean that $\gamma$ is belong to L and not belong to B.

Also,since,L is thethe set of lower bound of B,which means x$\in B$ is the upper bound of L.but $\alpha $ is greatest lower bound ,so x must be greater than $\alpha$ which implies x is not belong to L

Comment: Now take x=$\beta$ you can see the next result is true

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma<\alpha$, $\gamma$ is not an upper bound for L (since $\alpha$ was the **least** upper bound). It is written above in italics that every element in B must be an upper bound for L. Thus $\gamma$ is not in B.

We know that $\alpha \le x$ for every $x \in B$ because B is a set of upper bounds(from italics again) of L, and $\alpha$ is the **least** upper bound for L.

Also, $\alpha$ being an upper bound for L literally means that every element in L is less than or equal to $\alpha$. Thus if some $\beta$ is greater than $\alpha$, $\beta$ is not an element of L.